# Can an ImageView be a global variable?

Tags: java, android, variables, methods, imageview

In my java code in Android Studio, I have lots of methods which reference the same ImageView `head`, such as this method:

```
public void blue(View view) {
    ImageView head = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    head.bringToFront();
    blueOn = true;
    redOn = false;
}
```

Because of this, I want to make `head` a global variable with a code like this:

```
ImageView head = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);

public void blue(View view) {
    head.bringToFront();
    blueOn = true;
    redOn = false;
}
```

but this gives errors, is there something wrong with this part of the code or could the error be somewhere else?

Comment: you can declare it as a global variable , but you should initialize it by the **findViewById(...)** in your `onCreate` or `onViewCreated` methods depending on your application structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out below code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity{

private ImageView head;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        head=  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    }

public void blue(View view) {
    head.bringToFront();
    blueOn = true;
    redOn = false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

it can , but you need to do findviewbyid inside the oncreate because you can't findviewbyid before there is an activity, and after setting layout so the id can be found in this particular layout.

```
ImageView head;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    head = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
}
```

Comment: If I do that, is the `head` variable not then local to the `onCreate` method?

Comment: the refrence is the same but the initialization happens in the oncreate , and don't forget do not call that imageview before , it will cause a null exception

Answer (score 0):

It can be a global variable and I think your problem is in the implementation. Can you publish **full** code of that activity?